# Does angular 16 have the same components as Kendo UI?

Tags: angular, kendo-ui

We have built a ton of grid components and other components using angular material. Why should we at this point start using Kendo UI? Is there some new features of Kendo UI that aren't supported in angular still? or can I pretty much do anything in angular (in a reasonable amount of time) that I can in kendo?

Comment: "Just wanted to get the opinion of a few people here" - please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: "Is X really worth it" is always still going to sound opinion-based, and "Is there some new features" doesn't sound focused enough to me - it's not asking a *specific* programming question IMO.

Comment: @JonSkeet I altered the title

Answer (score 1):

Kendo UI in my opinion has a lot of great features especially around the grid. I do think angular material has came a long ways since kendo ui started and has almost equalized the quality as kendo UI. It depends on what you want. I prefer angular material since there is a greater user base (developers) that know it.